# In JSP technology, what's the difference between a translation error vs a compilation error?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Compilation error, fine it's the typical error you get when put wrong code. But how about this thing I'm reading about translation error?? I've never encountered something like that in normal java. It's either it doesn't compile or it compiles.. pls help calrify what is a translation error? Where does it come into the picture between

- compliation error (i know about)
- runtime exception (i know   about)
- translation error ----?????

Comment: Have you searched for it on google?

Comment: @RohitJain Would I have asked if I found the answer on Google?? Of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Translation Error :** This type of Error occurs during the initial request. When a JSP page is first requested and goes through the
>   initial translation from a JSP source file into a corresponding
>   Servlet class file.

**JSP Page Translation:**

> A java servlet file is generated from the JSP source file. This is the
>   first step in its tedious multiple phase life cycle. In the
>   translation phase, the container validates the syntactic correctness
>   of the JSP pages and tag files. The container interprets the standard
>   directives and actions, and the custom actions referencing tag
>   libraries used in the page.

To read more about JSP - Life Cycle visit http://javapapers.com/jsp/jsp-life-cycle-explain/

Answer (score 1):

With in the **The Life Cycle of a JSP Page**

> Those errors while Static data is transformed into code that will emit the data into the response stream.

[Read docs on the same Translation and Compilation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahe.html#bnahf)

Answer (score 1):

A translation and compilation error occurs during the life-cycle of a JSP page.

Translation errors occur when the JSP page is being translated to servlets and has to do with syntax errors in the JSP code. During translation each type of the data in the JSP page is treated differently,for example set and get properties are converted into method calls for javaBeans components etc.So a translation error would occur if the JSP page could not be translated to a servlet effectively.
  Compilation error occurs after a translation has occured(JSP page translated to servlet) that it occurs during the compilation of the translated servlet from the JSP and has to do more of the logic of your code than the syntax.
  If an error is either a translation or compilation error,the server will return a jasper exception and a message that includes the name of the JSP page.
  To learn more about translation and compilation:http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahe.html