# How can a JSP compilation error NOT be a translation error?

Tags: jsp, compiler-errors

From the Bridgewater SCWCD text:

> You can legally embed one `<%--` comment inside another, it's just not a sensible thing to do, for the translator will think the outer comment has ended as soon as it encounters the inner comment end marker. Doing this may lead to compilation errors, but is not in itself a cause for a translation error.

Although I understand that a JSP is translated into a generated servlet, I guess I'm having trouble determining what will cause a translation error vs. a response code vs. a compilation error.

Searching yielded this: 
[In JSP technology, what's the difference between a translation error vs a compilation error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033154/in-jsp-technology-whats-the-difference-between-a-translation-error-vs-a-compil)
but it didn't quite answer my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A translation error happens when your JSP is malformed enough that it cannot be translated into Java source code for the generated servlet. If you did not close a comment tag this would happen, for example.

A compilation error happens when the Java compiler cannot compile the source code for the generated servlet (created in the translation step above).

An error response code happens at runtime when the servlet (compiled and deployed) does not like something (for example invalid request parameters).